# If $B \subseteq A$ and $f:A \to B$ is 1-1, it must be onto

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $B \subseteq A$ and $f: A \to B$ be a 1-1 function, then $f$ must be onto.

I understand that $f$ is onto if and only if every element of $B$ is in the image of $f$...

I believe this statement is true then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true by the Pigeonhole Principle if $B$ is a finite set, but need not be true, otherwise. In fact, if $B$ is finite, $B\subseteq A$ and $f:A\to B$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is onto, and in fact $A=B.$

To see why it need not be true when $B$ is infinite, let $A$ be the set of positive integers, and $B$ the set of positive integers not equal to $1$. Then $B$ is a *proper* subset of $A,$ but while the map $f:A\to B$ given by $f(n)=2n$ is one-to-one, it is not onto.

Comment: In the first paragraph, your claim "both statements imply that $A=B$" doesn't seem right as stated. In context, "onto" should mean "onto $B$", which doesn't imply that $f$ is one-to-one or that $A = B$.

Comment: @Trevor: Not sure where my brain was when I wrote that. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

This is false: Choose $A = B = \mathbb{N}$ and define $$f(n) = n + 1$$

---

If $A$ is finite, then the statements are equivalent.